# Cannot add a value other than a string to a nested hashmap

Tags: hashmap, rust

I want to create a `HashMap` with a nested structure like this convoluted example:

```
{
   type: boy
   name: Phineas
   father:
       type: man
       name: Lawrence
}
```

In Rust, this would be:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut lawrence = HashMap::new();
lawrence.insert("type", "man");
lawrence.insert("name", "Lawrence");
let mut phineas = HashMap::new();
phineas.insert("type", "boy");
phineas.insert("name", "Phineas");
phineas.insert("father", lawrence);
```

But `HashMap` values only can be strings, it seems; if I try to compile I get:

```
expected &str, found struct `std::collections::HashMap`
```

I checked the documentation but could not find an easy solution to build up a similar data structure.

Comment: `phineas.insert("father", lawrence);`
did you mean "lawrence"? Elsewise there is your problem, that you can't insert two different types into the same hashmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're coming from a dynamically-typed language.  In that case, you *really* need to read through the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/), as Rust is a *very* different beast.  Rust is statically typed, so what you're trying to do here is pretty much just not going to work, and definitely isn't how you're meant to use the language.

In this particular case, there's no easy answer because I don't know what your goal here is.  Data structure modelling in Rust is done through a combination of [`struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/structs.html)s, [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/enums.html)s, collections like `Vec` and `HashMap`, utility types like `Option`, and the various pointer types like `Box`, `Rc`, *etc.*  What specific combination of these you need is down to what you're trying to represent, how you intend to build it, and how you intend to use it.

One *possible* formulation would be:

```
struct Person {
    kind: PersonKind,
    name: String,
    father: Option<Box<Person>>,
}

enum PersonKind {
    Boy,
    Man,
}
```

Comment: Yes, I come from dynamic languages; I know I was making a rookie mistake here; thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) is a generic. When you insert the first time the compiler determines the type and won't let you use another type.

```
pub struct HashMap<K, V, S = RandomState> { /* fields omitted */ }

pub fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V>
```

`V` is the type of your values and `K` the type of the keys. Since Rust has a static type system, this must be considered.